# error Failed to set title: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

Tags: javascript

this code is supposed to fetch a URL and pull the only text there and then make the change to the twitch stream title. what am i doing wrong?

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node
const twitchAPI = 'https://api.twitch.tv/helix';
const clientId = 'censored';
const clientSecret = 'censored';
const refreshToken = 'censored';
const accessToken = 'censored';
const channelName = 'censored';
const url = 'https://api.kyroskoh.xyz/valorant/v1/mmr/eu/CEN%20Astro/EUWE?show=combo&display=0';

// Set initial title
let currentRank = '';
setTitle('OMW to Diamond [Unknown Rank] | !rank !sens');

// Poll for updates every 5 seconds
setInterval(async () => {
  try {
    const module = await import('node-fetch');
    const fetch = module.default;
    
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.text();
    // Extract rank from response data
    const rankRegex = /<body>(.*)<\/body>/;
    const match = data.match(rankRegex);
    if (match) {
      const rank = match[1];
      if (rank !== currentRank) {
        currentRank = rank;
        setTitle(`OMW to Diamond [${rank}] | !rank !sens`);
        console.log(`Title updated to: OMW to Diamond [${rank}] | !rank !sens`);
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Failed to fetch rank: ${error}`);
  }
}, 5000);

// Helper function to set the stream title using Twitch API
async function setTitle(title) {
    try {
      const module = await import('node-fetch');
      const fetch = module.default;
  
      const response = await fetch(`${twitchAPI}/channels?broadcaster_name=${channelName}`, {
        headers: {
          'Client-ID': clientId,
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
      });
      const data = await response.json();
  
      const broadcasterId = data.data[0].broadcaster_id;
      const patchResponse = await fetch(`${twitchAPI}/channels?broadcaster_id=${broadcasterId}`, {
        method: 'PATCH',
        headers: {
          'Client-ID': clientId,
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ title }),
      });
      console.log(`Successfully set title to: ${title}`);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(`Failed to set title: ${error}`);
    }
}
```

i tried adding some console.log statements to my code to print out the data returned by the API at various points. came out with

```
{
  error: 'Bad Request',
  status: 400,
  message: 'Missing required parameter "broadcaster_id"'
}
Failed to set title: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
```

i expected it to have changed the stream title

Comment: Are these two separate errors?  Which specific operation produces each?  It seems like the latter error is the result of [poor error handling from] the former error.  Does that first fetch request in `setTitle` require a `broadcaster_id` value?  (Which may be unfortunate, since that appears to be how you *get* that value...)